# Can a cobblestone pickaxe mine Lapis Lazuli ore?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can we mine lapis lazuli ore with a cobble stone pickaxe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick visit to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lapis_Lazuli_Ore) will tell you that you can mine Lapis Lazuli Ore with a Stone Pickaxe or better.